# Count number of rows retrieved from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, row

```
public int countBookings() throws SQLException{

    ResultSet rs=null;
    PMDBController db=new PMDBController();
    int rowCount=0;

    db.getConnection();

    String dbQuery="SELECT COUNT(User) AS UserCount FROM INSTRUCTORBOOKING WHERE USER ='"+instructorId+"'";

    rs=db.readRequest(dbQuery);

    try{
        if(rs.next()){
            instructorId=rs.getString("UserCount");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    rs.last();
    rowCount=rs.getRow();
    db.terminate();

    return rowCount;
}
```

Basically what this method is supposed to do is count the number of rows gotten from the database. However, it always returns 1 no matter what is inside. Help!

Comment: Note that aggregate functions normally include a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: 'not necessarily normally' - what does that mean?

Comment: NOTE: `Your query will also work fine . Make sure that there is more than one "jack" as user in your table` . And in your code `instructorId` is the desired value that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a problem in your query. Since you only select 1 user you will always get a count of 1.

```
"SELECT COUNT(User) AS UserCount FROM INSTRUCTORBOOKING WHERE USER ='"+instructorId+"'"
```

Try removing your WHERE clause? Maybe that's not exactly what you want, but we can't see your data model from just one query.

Comment: What i want to do is count the number of rows where the Column User has the Value "Jack" for example.

Comment: Then just use a value from result (instructorId = rs.getString("UserCount");) as a counter. instructorId is actually a number of users (NOT a number of rows in a result which is always = 1)

Answer (score 0):

`rowCount = rs.getInt("UserCount");` instead of `instructorId = rs.getString("UserCount");` would do the trick. Or in other words --- you read the number of rows but into variable instructorId.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows will always be 1. It's the count i.e. the value of that row you need to look at as your query is designed to return the count of rows and not the actual rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(User) AS UserCount FROM INSTRUCTORBOOKING WHERE USER ='"+instructorId+"'"
```

You have wrongly interpreted that the number of rows would be the count you are looking for.